# Why is phantom driver going in infinite loop while selecting an option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, chromium

Select type on web page:

```
<select id="FILE_TYPE" data-context="Input" onchange="filterValueChanged('FILE_TYPE','false','-##ALL##-');display_submitForm('DEPENDENCY','','DISPLAY_6061638','SOURCE_CONTROL_ID=FILE_TYPE' );">
<option value="-##ALL##-" selected="">[ALL]</option>
<option value="AB_CD">AB CD Types</option>
<option value="CA_BD">CA BD Types</option>
<option value="CONFIG">Configuration Types</option>
<option value="XYZ">X Y Z Types</option>
<option value="ST_MT">ST MT Types</option>
```

Code to find element is working fine:

```
Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FILE_TYPE")));
System.out.println(selectBox.getOptions().size()); // printing "6" 
selectBox.getOptions().forEach(e -> getValue(e)); // printing all options text
```

Now I want to select "X Y Z Types" value in select tag. I tried selecting with following ways:

1) Index

```
selectBox.selectByIndex(4);
```

2) Visible Text

```
selectBox.selectByVisibleText("X Y Z Types");
```

3) Value

```
selectBox.selectByValue("XYZ");
```

4) XPATH

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"FILE_TYPE\"]/option[5]")).click();
```

But nothing is working instead it is taking control to infinite loop.

```
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.614Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - start
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - is topWindow
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - check if window registered
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - window found: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.723Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.832Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.942Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:23.050Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:23.159Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:23.269Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
....(infinitely)
```

Update: (As Bill suggested, it could be page loading issue) I do see spinner rotating continuously when I try to manually access this webpage. (pic below)

[image]

[image]

Update 2:
Adding initialization of driver and browser (as per DebanjanB suggestion)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", seleniumDriverPATH);
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ImmutableMap<String, String> commandLineArguments = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
        .put("web-security", "false")
        .put("ssl-protocol", "any")
        .put("ignore-ssl-errors", "true")
        .put("webdriver-loglevel", "DEBUG")
        .put("ssl-client-certificate-file", certificatePath)
        .put("ssl-client-key-passphrase", certificatePassword).build();
String[] params = commandLineArguments.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> String.format("--%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new String[0]);
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, params);
cap.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
```

Update 3: I tried with IE 11 (which was not showing loading spinner) but still getting same issue as - control going into infinite loop while clicking on below line

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions. elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='FILE_TYPE' and @data-context='Input']//option[@value='XYZ']"))).click();
```

Comment: Reinitialize the select element immediately before attempting to select an option.  Your previous access of the select may be resetting its values.  I'm not sure why this works but it often does.

Comment: @BillHileman I have commented all previous access (getting size n element text) but still its going in infinite loop..

Comment: It's apparently waiting for a page load, so you might want to do a screen capture before the loop and see what's going on - it might be visible,  Also, does the same code run if it's not in headless mode?

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks Bill for all your suggestions..I tried taking screenshot but nothing wrong in it..and also tried running browser with 
 options.addArguments("--headless");  still same behaviour.

Comment: Are you able to run it without the headless option?  What I'm hoping for is that you might be able to view the DOM while it appears to be looping to see if there are web elements in place (but perhaps not visible) to intentionally block user input.

Comment: It is going in infinite loop with headless option as well. But 1 thing to add I can see spinner rotating continuously with page title when I try manually to access webpage. I will add pic of that in update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from your question update and the snapshots that the page havn't completed loading hence you see the following errors ;

```
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.614Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - start
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - is topWindow
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - check if window registered
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.692Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - page.onConsoleMessage - window found: true
[DEBUG - 2018-03-06T19:36:22.723Z] Session [91f59080-2175-11e8-9d57-a93d0ef995b3] - _execFuncAndWaitForLoadDecorator - Page Loading in Session: true
```

### Solution

A possible solution would be to induce [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause set to [*elementToBeSelected*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeSelected-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

```
Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FILE_TYPE")));
System.out.println(selectBox.getOptions().size()); // printing "6" 
selectBox.getOptions().forEach(e -> getValue(e)); // printing all options text
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions. elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='FILE_TYPE' and @data-context='Input']//option[@value='XYZ']"))).click();
```

Comment: I triad with exact same  line you suggested WebDriverWait. But still its stuck in infinite loop of that "Page loading in session..". I know its weird because after wait for 20 sec it should stop trying and exit the code but I think control in going in infinte loop even when it 1st encounter click..not sure why..

Comment: @Manvi Can you update the question with the initialization of the Webdriver & WebBrowser ?